# iAd and Admob integration countries added to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, iad

I am creating an app that requests iAds and uses Admob in cases where no iAd is received.

I have free and paid versions and use preprocessor macros to differentiate between these versions.

There are 2 possible scenarios:

1. Country supports iAds and Admob (Use iAds code and revert to Admob where no iAd is received)
2. Country supports Admob only (Use Admob code only)

I understand how to deal with these scenarios (using preprocessor macros).  However, if a country that is currently not supported by iAds is then added to the list of supported countries, is there any easy way to move them on to use iAds?

I understand from reading Apple documentation that they do not want developers to request iAds for countries where iAds are unsupported.

My plan is to create 2 free versions (1 for each of the scenarios above).  However, I'm not sure how to move a country from scenario 2 to scenario 1.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an ad mediation solution, such as [AdMob Mediation](http://support.google.com/admob/answer/2413211?hl=en&)? You get the following benefits:

1. You don't have to write up the mediation fallback logic in your own code.
2. Server-side traffic allocation - it's simple to move traffic from one network to another without having to re-release your app.
3. Country-level targeting. No need for two free versions. Just set up your trafficking to a default allocation that serves only AdMob, and set up country level targeting (which will override the default targeting) to serve up iAd first, and then AdMob if iAd fails.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'll need to have a look into it. At the moment I'm switching between them using code which makes it difficult to turn each source on or off.

Comment: This would work in most cases.  However, Admob Mediation asks you to enter an Ad Size.  My app is in landscape mode and the correct ad sizes are not listed (480x32 for iPhone and 1024x66 for iPad).  Would this option still work for me?  Where is this Ad Size parameter used?  Would it work if I select the closest size or is this parameter used to find any ads to use?

Comment: iAd sizes are unfortunately slightly different than most other networks. However, if you're just using iAd and AdMob, you can use the "SMART_BANNER" format, which requests full width ads. The iAd adapter supports this, and AdMob supports this as well (you'd get 480x32 and 1024x90 with AdMob).

Comment: I am using iOS 6 and the smart banners don't work at all in the Admob SDK.  Presumably as Apple deprecated some methods that were used by the Admob SDK.  Is this what you mean when you refer to "SMART_BANNER"?

Comment: In Admob Mediation I have a page titled "Add Network Mediation Placement".  On this page I am asked to enter Name, Platform and Ad Size.  What Ad Size would I select for iPhone and iPad?  None of the sizes match for Admob or iAd ads (and SMART_BANNER isn't an option on the list).  What is the purpose of this drop down list?  Isn't the ad size specified in the request used?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking in Android constant form. By smart banner I mean [kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#ios-sizes) or the landscape version, depending on orientation. The front-end is a bit confusing because smart banner is not on the drop down, but you can select 320x50 in this case. The size specified on the front-end isn't actually used in your app - it's just that the list of supported networks depend on the size selected. In this case, you can just specify 320x50 since iAd and AdMob both support 320x50 and smart banners.

Comment: I trust that this would work if the smart banners worked.  However, I am having problems getting this returning banners for Admob and iAd.  I am having to set the banner size manually until this is fixed for iOS6.  I think I will have to go with what I have for the moment and replace with Admob Mediation when this issue is resolved.